# Pandas GroupBy with 2 indexes: want to use % of second index as aggregate value, rather than .count()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm doing a GroupBy in Pandas with two indexes, see below:

[image]

It's currently grouped by "count", but I'd like to have the values instead be the **% of each month**. This way I'd be able to **better compare each month**, rather than comparing counts of each month, which isn't fair as there are different numbers of entries each month.

I.e. this is what the graph **currently looks like**, whereas I want the bars to show % of each month, rather than count:

[image]

This is what I'm **trying to make**, with % of each month compared: 
[image]

I have no clue how I could achieve this: maybe a lambda function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
int_group = (interactions.groupby('MM-YYYY')['Description']
                .value_counts(normalize=True)
                .unstack('Description')
            )

int_group.plot.bar()
```